# Wordpress subpage redirection of static pages

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a WordPress page set up with some static pages, one of these is [www.mysite.com/courses](http://www.mysite.com/courses)
This page loads a custom template that gets a list of active courses from a database and lists them up beautifully.

When you click a course, you're directed to for example [www.mysite.com/courses/34/](http://www.mysite.com/courses/34/) and another template is loaded that displays the course data for the course with that ID.

Here is my code:

```php
<?php
/**
  * Header content
  */
get_header();

if ( $post->post_name === 'courses' ):
    if ( preg_match('/^\/courses\/[0-9]+\/$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || preg_match('/^\/courses\/[0-9]+\/?.+$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ):
        include 'pages/courses/view-single.php';
    else:
        include 'pages/courses/view.php';
    endif;
elseif ( $post->post_name === 'contact' ):
    include 'pages/contact.php';
elseif ( $post->post_name === 'course-offers' ):
    include 'pages/offers.php';
else:
    include 'pages/default-post-view.php';
endif;

/**
 * Footer content
 */
get_footer();
```

Before I upgraded from v5.1 to the latest version of WordPress (5.5) this worked right out of the box without any special settings changed, however, after the update, WordPress simply redirects back to the original course page (mysite.com/courses)

I tried messing around with the permalink settings within WordPress to no avail.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it possible to do this differently? How can I achieve similar functionality again?

Comment: WP 5.5 seems to have introduced a number of bugs, based on the posts I see here and elsewhere, although I don't know if this is one of them. Have you tried to narrow down what part is failing, e.g. which `if` clause is being triggered, is `preg_match` returning the course id etc. Your code looks ok so its hard for us to tell what it might be without more info.

Comment: @FluffyKitten As far as I can tell, it's not hitting the if/preg_match function at all and seems to be "jumping" over it so to speak. It's almost as if some rewrite rule is ignoring all subpages.  If i try to manually type in mysite.com/courses/test it's being handled as a non-existant page outside of the have_posts() loop.

Comment: Can you try adding `var_dump($post->post_name);die();` just after the header, and let us know what it shows?

Comment: @FluffyKitten ```string(7) "courses" ``` is all its showing unfortunately. I also tried dumping $_SERVER and checking the output as I click a link inside /courses/, but its not even touching the actual pseudo-subpage and seems more like its reloading the /courses/ page.

Comment: I as hoping it had something unusual like a hidden character (but it is 7 characters so its right) or a space or... well I don't know, but something to make it a different type and fail the identical `===` check! So does the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` actually have the course id in it?

Comment: I was hoping that ```$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']``` would at least show something, but it seems like WordPress refuses to load any subpage with numbers.  The request uri stays the same and the page just seems to reload. If I try /courses/test, it loads it as page outside the have_posts() loop, (I let this default to my 404 error message basically, like "Oops. We couldn't find what you were looking for." generic message.) Could it have something to do with the permalink settings?  I tried messing with them, but the outcome did not change.

Comment: Oooh that's right... I remember seeing something about problems with slugs that were just numbers. Could you change the code to use a prefix (something like `www.mysite.com/courses/id-34/`) and then strip the prefix in your code above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219988/discussion-between-dixos-and-fluffykitten).

Comment: Glad you got sorted! You should add your comment from the chat here as a comment on the question so others will see it (they might not think to check the chat), or better yet expand on it as an answer :)